# Format sql query in TOAD 7.

Tags: sql, format, toad

In toad's older version i can easily able to format the query in

Toad's Query editor by

```
  right click > Format Code.
```

But in newer version of Toad 7 i can't able to find this Format option. Can any one help me from where i can Format My Query.

(**how to FORMAT QUERY in TOAD 7?**)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**TOAD FOR ORACLE**

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+F should help you

To format a statement Select the statement you want to select and click `»` on the Edit toolbar.

To format an entire script Click `»` on the Edit toolbar.

**Tip**:You can also right-click the script and select Formatting Tools |
Format Code.

See the [documentation](https://support.software.dell.com/download/downloads?id=3382171)

**TOAD FOR MYSQL**

Format SQL

Use the formatter to modify the layout of SQL in the Editor, including inserting headers, adding or removing extra lines, and changing the case for keywords.

To format SQL

Click `Paint shaped box` on the Editor toolbar to format the contents of the Editor window. You can also format a partial statement in the Editor by selecting it before applying [formatting](http://dev.toadformysql.com/webhelp/ToadforMySQL.htm#Editor/formatting_SQL.htm).

See [documentation](http://dev.toadformysql.com/webhelp/ToadforMySQL.htm)

Comment: this short-cut is for Find/Replace in Files

Comment: mysql TOAD 7's Query Editor

Comment: In RIGHT CLICK Format Code option is not available. But thanks its done

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, in Toad 5 for SQLServer, the button to format code is "2 yellow triangles pointing right". In my fresh installation, this button is on the toolbar, beside the dropdown box to select the db environment.

If you want to assign a shortcut, find it at Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard | Editor | Tools | FormatCode.

Hope it helps, it took very long to find these buttons. Wish they'd make the controls the same as Toad for Oracle..

Answer (score 1):

You can format from the menu bar: Editor > Format Code > choose the exact format from the format list.
In case anyone's interested, for toad 8 for MySQL, there is an OOTB hot-key. Simply select the code you want to format, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In toad you can easily able to format the query by this shortcut ;

Toad's Query editor;

```
SHIFT+CTRL+F
```